# Query Qubole data in Python

Tags: python, qubole

I'm trying to query Qubole data in Python, but running into some issues. Below is my code:

```
from qds_sdk.qubole import Qubole

Qubole.configure(api_token="api_token", api_url="https://us.qubole.com/api")

from qds_sdk.commands import *

presto=PrestoCommand.create(query="select A, B from table limit 10", label="presto_shared")
```

However, when I tried to extract the result:

`presto.get_results()`

The output is like this:

```
2021-02-15 12:49:23.449 2021-02-15 12:49:23.446

2021-02-06 08:55:35.367 2021-02-06 08:55:35.363

2021-03-02 20:56:22.565 2021-03-02 20:56:13.678

2021-02-15 12:49:16.473 2021-02-15 12:49:16.47

2021-02-15 12:48:39.467 2021-02-15 12:48:39.462

2021-02-15 12:48:38.776 2021-02-15 12:48:18.892

2021-02-15 12:48:24.96  2021-02-15 12:48:24.956

2021-02-15 12:48:21.234 2021-02-15 12:48:21.23

2021-02-15 12:48:02.686 2021-02-15 12:48:02.684

2021-02-15 12:47:57.592 2021-02-15 12:47:57.589
```

The class type is "NoType".. Also, no table headers...

I guess, something was wrong with *get_results()*? Thanks!

Comment: Why is that wrong?  What should be in A and B?

Comment: A and B should be column name... There is no column name in the output.. Also, the class of output is "NoType"... Looks like couldn't convert to DataFrame

Comment: Why would it convert to a dataframe?  Qubole doesn't do that.  `get_results() ` returns columns in text form, space separated or column separated.

Comment: I'm wandering if could convert it in Python.

Comment: Of course.  If you really want, the Qubole examples show how to have the data returned as a CSV file, and `pandas` can read CSV files.

Comment: Read the example: https://github.com/qubole/qds-sdk-py/blob/unreleased/example/qubole_presto_api_example.py